# Graceful Thread Termination C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have the following code

```
    public void FXSMessageProc()
    {
        WaitHandle[] handles = new WaitHandle[] 
            { _msgSignal, _terminateSignal };
        while(WaitHandle.WaitAny(handles, Timeout.Infinite) == 0)
            lock (_lock) simconnect?.ReceiveMessage();
    }
```

The Handles -> _msgSignal set by a third-party library, _terminateSignal set by myself. Is the code above the ok? Should I mark both handles as volatile?

Regards,
Ron.

Comment: What's probably not good is running a `lock` in a tight loop like that. What does it do to you CPU?

Comment: Thanks, at present it looks ok maxing at 5.9%, will give it a proper test under load and let you know.